# Modal con un foreach en laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap

Buenas noches tengo un conflicto y es que lo he estado intentando de muchas maneras y aun no llego a una solucion necesito que la informacion que esta tirada desde un foreach y un customer_tag pueda visualizarse toda la informacion en ves de desplegarse toda la información como ya lo hace, ocupo que esas misma informacion se muestre pero en modal, para que al desplegar no importe si se abre hacia abajo o hacia arriba, 
a continuacion les envio el extracto de codigo y el script.

```
                 @if($file->link != null)
                  @if($file->grupo == $file->idgrupo)
                  @foreach($files as $arch)
                   @if($arch->link == $file->link)
                   @if($arch->tipo == 'SI')
                      <button class="BTBoletin" id="myBtn"  onclick="showBoletin({{$file->grupo}});">{{$file->titulo}}</button>

                        <li   style="padding: 2px 4px 0px 4px;">
                           <div class="ClickBoletin" id="">
                                  <div class="posisionBoletin"> 
                                    <span class="titulosdelboletin Micro{{$file->grupo}}" id="holax" >
                                         </span>
                            <div customer_tag="COS{{$file->idgrupo}}">
                              <img style="margin-bottom: -5%; margin-top: 1%;" src="images/footprintsignificative.jpeg"  width="14"/>
                              <a href="/storage/app/public/boletines/{{ $file->link }}" style="color:#000" target="_blank">
                              <span  ><p style="margin-left: 6%;" id="nombredeltitulo">{{$arch->name}}</p></span>
                             </a>
                           </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                              </li>
                   @endif

                   @if($arch->tipo == 'NO')

                    <li   style="padding: 19px; display: none;" customer_tag="COSa{{$file->idgrupo}}">
                          <!-- <li  style="padding: 19px;"  >   -->

                        <div class="mostrarBoletin">

                            <a href="/storage/app/public/boletines/{{ $file->link }}" style="color:#000" target="_blank">
                              <div class="TituloBoletines">
                                <div class="colorBulletNorma">
                                <strong> > </strong>
                                </div>
                                <span style="font-weight: bold;  " ><p style="font-weight: bold; color: green;"  id="nombredeltitulo">{{$arch->name}}</p></span>
                              </div>
                           </a>
                     </div> 
                     <!-- </li>  -->

                   </li>

                   @endif


                   @endif
                  @endforeach
                  @endif
                 @endif
```

esta es la vista esta hecho en un .blade.php 
seguidamente voy a pegar el script

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
      var cont = 0;
      function showBoletin(boletin){   
        var desplegue = $("#COSa"+ boletin).val();
        var inicial = boletin;

        if(cont == 0){
          //$("#COSa"+ boletin).show();

          $("[customer_tag='COSa"+ boletin +"']").slideDown( "slow" );/*.show();*/
          cont = cont += 1;
        }
        else{
          //$("#COSa"+ boletin).hide();  

          $("[customer_tag='COSa"+ boletin +"']").hide("slow");
           cont = cont -= 1;
        }

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es ¿mostrar un modal al pulsar un botón?

Comment: Correcto si ves el la parte del if por el tipo hay un botón que tiene el título eso se despliega unos archivos los que no son tipo si. Esos que se despliegan tipo no ocupó que sea por modal ya intente poniendo una clase boostrap pero no funciona

Comment: El problema lo tienes con el uso de HTML / bootstrap, puede que no uses alguna clase correctamente o no cierres un tag HTML donde toca. Te recomiendo simplificar el problema, una vez tienes la página cargada en el navegador, usas la opción de "Guardar como..." tendrás sólo HTML, CSS y JS, en su caso. Usa un validador de HTML, embellecedor o lo que sea, para comprobar cierre de tags, si estan correctos. Versiona los ficheros (Git), simplifica el HTML si puedes y trata de encontrar el problema con bootstrap.
Saludos.